# This is equation is giving me issues $x^2 - 6x + 15 = 0 $

Tags: quadratics

I was given this equation $x^2 - 6x + 15 = 0 $

I tried to look for numbers whose sum is big and product of ac and i could not find any. I tried using the quadratic formula
$$\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
 and this is what i got

$x = \frac{6\pm\sqrt{-24}}{2}$

I just dont know what to do from here: any help would be appreacited.

Comment: The equation simply has 2 imaginary roots.

Comment: Yes, this equation has no real solutions.

Comment: $\sqrt{-24}=24i$

Comment: you must learn more about imaginary numbers

Comment: @cardinal $\sqrt{-24} = \sqrt{24} \cdot i$.

Comment: oh, i must sleep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to find the roots as follow:
Note that:

$$ i^2 = -1$$

$$ x = \frac{6\pm \sqrt{-24}}{2}=\frac{6\pm i\sqrt{24}}{2} $$

$$ x= \frac{6\pm 2i\sqrt{6}}{2} = 3\pm i\sqrt{6}$$

Further explanation ($i^2 = -1$):

let $a = \sqrt{-24}$

$a^2 = -24= 24 \times -1= 24i^2$

$a =\pm \sqrt{24} \times \sqrt{i^2}= \pm i\sqrt{24} = \pm i \times \sqrt{4} \times \sqrt{6} = \pm2i\sqrt{6}$

Comment: the writing $i=\sqrt{-1}$ is false you must put $i²=-1$ instead

Comment: @Agawa001, Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Any reasons for the downvotes? Makes no sense to me!

Comment: I didn't downvoted but it should be $\color{red}+ 6$

Comment: now it looks better

Comment: please can you explain the steps? I will appreciate. like how you got $2i\sqrt{6}$

Comment: @user249954, but you've accepted the above answer and you stated you understood the solution. You may want to read this-http://www.purplemath.com/modules/complex.htm

Comment: Actually I thought i did until i tried the next one and didnt. Sorry about that,

Comment: @user249954, I'll re-edit my post to explain further.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach

> $$x^2-6x+15=0$$

$$x^2-6x=-15$$

$$x^2-6x+9=-6$$

$$(x-3)^2=-6$$

Take the square root of both sides

$$x-3=i\sqrt6,\;x-3=-i\sqrt6$$

$$\boxed{\color{red}{x=3\pm i\sqrt6}}$$

Comment: It looks like i didnt fathom this so what would this be? $\sqrt{-47}$

Comment: @user249954 $\sqrt{-47}=i\sqrt{47}$